# Giving termux root privilege

Tags: sudo, termux

I have a rooted samsung a30 and android 9.0 (using latest stable magisk), I have installed latest termux and tsu and when I was prompted with magisk window I granted termux root privilege, but whenever I execute any command I get a 'permission denied' error, I have also done 'termux-setup-storage' and also tried 'termux-sudo' but nothing worked.

There's literally no solution found online for this!!

Edit: i'm trying to post an image but for some reason it's not appearing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoGoF.jpg

Comment: Try `su` instead of `tsu` command for starting root.

Comment: Try using `nano` command to edit and alter root permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write  'su' on termux, then give termux root

Answer (score 0):

In Termux on the Android system, you cannot directly obtain full administrator (root) privileges from within the Termux application.

Termux operates within an isolated environment and does not have access to system-level permissions.